# Nameserver invalid warning from an intoDNS.com test

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone

I made my own nameserver configuration, but as you can see in the picture and [the intodns.com link](https://intodns.com/boz.works), I am getting a (`hostname`) warning.

```
WARNING: At least one of your NS name does not seem a valid host name
The ones that do not seem valid:
ns2.bo(*).works ns1.bo(*).works
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Hosting provider nameserver IPs:**

```
5.250.241.34
5.250.242.34
```

**My dedicated IP:**

```
5.250.252.52
```

**My DNS Records:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Domain Provider DNS Settings:**

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Where am I making a mistake? Do I enter the dedicated IP in the fields? I could not understand! Why am I getting this error? How should it be properly configured?

Comment: Try with dnsviz.net or zonemaster.net they should provide more accurate results. Those are the only 2 online DNS troubleshooting tools I recommend. Current results with DNSViz are ok: https://dnsviz.net/d/boz.works/YHzHBQ/dnssec/. you just have 4 warnings regarding DNSSEC which can be summarized by: stop using SHA-1, see https://www.icann.org/en/blogs/details/its-time-to-move-away-from-using-sha-1-in-the-dns-24-1-2020-en for example for the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there's nothing wrong with the setup, but the tool you are using is reporting...

1. a false positive. Maybe the single test isn't aware of `.works` being a valid TLD.
2. about something that isn't really a problem. For example there aren't matching *reverse DNS* `PTR` records, but that isn't a requirement.

Comment: I suspect 1, and there seems to be a history of this being the case. See eg https://twitter.com/lonesync/status/557704995702050816

Comment: Also, the logo at the top of the page says it's still a **beta**.

Comment: Absolutely I agree. I just doubted myself, I guess I do it right. Thanks.